# How to identify the user of my website who just paid by clicking PayPal Buy Now button?

Tags: paypal

I have some difficulties when identity a user who buy my product, suppose a user click Buy Now button and finish the transaction and then return back to my website, how could I know which user just paid?

BTW, I use PayPal's [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/) to receive the transaction info about who buy my product, but I still don't know which user in my website has bought it, any ideas?

Comment: Java, but I think language does not matter, as I'm using REST API.

Comment: you should get the buyer name,buyer email address in PDT, can you show what response you get in PDT?

Comment: Yes I can get buyer's email address, but I don't know this email address correspond to which user in my website. My website does not need email to login, even so, it does not help, as the buyer's email may not equals to his login email. The link I give in my question list full PDT variables.

Comment: You have two approaches: either pass an identifier through a PayPal pass-through field (such as CUSTOM) which you have associated with the customer on your side, or use whatever mechanism (presumably cookie-based) you use to manage web sessions; when the user returns to your site you read your cookie and contine their web session.

Comment: Thank you @geewiz, I managed to do it using pass-through fields. If you wish you can put your comment as the answer so I can make as accepted answer.